# How add multiple steps in angular bootstrap tour?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm using the plugin [angular-bootstrap-tour](https://github.com/benmarch/angular-bootstrap-tour) and I want to add multiple steps to the same element, but the way that the md file describes only shows the case for a single element help, since that configuration is possible through element attributes, I can't find a way to add multiple steps to a element:

Here is an example for a element help:

```
<panel tour-step='', order='1', title='Step 1', content='This is the first step', placement='right'>
    Element content
</panel>
```

**So, how can I add more than one step to a same element?**